# In basketball, why can a team calling a timeout inbound the ball at midcourt after the timeout (effectively gaining ground for free)?

Tags: rules, basketball

For example: Seconds left on the clock in a close game, Team A scores a basket, and Team B calls timeout. After the timeout, Team B throws in the ball from halfway up the court. What's the reasoning behind this? They just save like 2 or 3 valuable seconds by calling a timeout... It seems a little weird and unfair.

Answer (score 2):

According to Chuck Klosterman, it just always was a part of the NBA.  (I don't believe it's a rule in most rule systems.)

Feel free to peruse [this fantastic piece of journalism on the sadly defunct Grantland](https://grantland.com/features/absurdity-nba-half-court-rule/).  He covers the topics of why it is thought to exist (to add excitement - things like Derek Fischer's Spur-Killing turnaround jumper, or even The Shot, probably happened because of this rule); but shows that it's been in the rules as far back as he can find rules.

I suspect it *does* exist because of the excitement factor, personally, and perhaps always has.  But there's no evidence, as far as I can tell, and as far as Chuck Klosterman can tell, who's a much better expert (and writer!) than I.